# error: Could not find: C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\zipalign.exe

Tags: android, genexus, sdk

Ao realizar o Build no main para smart device plataforma android, no final do processo recebo a seguinte mensagem:
error: Could not find: C:\android-sdk\platform-tools\zipalign.exe

Já Removi e instalei novamente o SDK do android porém a mesagem persiste. Esse aquivo está localizado em outro path, no caso na pasta: C:\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\zipalign.exe

Existe alguma configuração para configurar esse path?

Answer (score 3):

Resposta neste link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24539245/genexus-build-for-android-fails-with-could-not-find-sdk-platform-tools-zipali

"A partir do SDK Tools 23, zipalign.exe foi movido novamente. Ele não está mais em seu local anterior (em \ tools), está na pasta \ build-tools.

Este problema foi corrigido em GeneXus X Evolution 3 Upgrade 1 (assim como Evolution 2 Atualização 7).

Por enquanto, você pode evitar este problema, seguindo estes passos:

1. Verifique que pelo menos uma versão do SDK   está instalado (isto é necessário para a compilacao de qualquer maneira).
2. Copie o arquivo de zipalign.exe da pasta "\build-tools" para "\tools" ou "\platform-tools"."

Comment: Antes demais seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow em português. Como este é um site em português as perguntas e respostas devem ser escritas em português. Se você pretende responder valendo-se de uma resposta do site em inglês deve traduzi-la antes de a postar aqui.